# Does "until" convey certainty?

Tags: meaning

Consider this sentence,

> Until this is proven wrong, we will believe it to be true.

Does it mean either;

- This *will be* proven wrong, and we will continue to believe it is true in the meantime
- If this is proven to be wrong, we will believe it's wrong, and we will believe it is true otherwise.

So, when someone use *until* like this, does it mean the mentioned thing **will happen** or **might happen** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Until*** simply means *up to the point in time when*.  So your sentence could be rephrased as "*Up to the point in time when this is proven wrong, we will believe it to be true.*"

Any certainty or uncertainty derives from the context and the implications of the sentence and not from the use of the word *until*.

I could say, "Until the subway is completed we will take the bus."  From this context it is easy to infer that we believe the subway *will* be completed and when it is, we will start using it.

The other thing to point out here is that in your example sentence I would expect to hear emphasis on the word *proven*.  In other words I may acknowledge that many people believe it to be incorrect, but until it is actually *proven* I will continue to believe it.

Answer (score 2):

If the sentence is taken literally, either interpretation could hold.  However, for most readers or listeners, only the second interpretation is ever thought of.   That is, all but a tiny fraction of auditors take the meaning to be as below, where *X* denotes the thing in question which is not yet proved or disproved:

> We believe *X* at present, and will continue to do so, until such time (if any) as *X* is disproved.

Under the second interpretation, there is no implication that *X* will or might be proved wrong, but such proof is not thought impossible.  The first interpretation, on the other hand, seems to require belief that *X will* be proved wrong.  But if you know or believe *X* will be proved wrong, it is willful perversity to meanwhile believe in it; so apparently the first interpretation is unlikely to ever be correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Until this is proven wrong, we will believe it to be true.

Until is unconcerned with whether the associated condition will be true, will not be true, probably/possibly will/will not be true, or will never be true. Another way of reading the OP's sentence is:

> As long as this is true, we will believe it to be true.

Certainty/uncertainty is determined entirely by the condition rather than by the conjunction :)

Comment: Not sure what your first sentence means.  Your second sentence is quite wrong: 'not known to be false' is not 'true' even in a computer. And your third sentence is also mistaken; certainty in an observer is not, alas, a function of truth.

Comment: @TimLymington Then it's a good thing that we are not debating Boolean logic here.